# Unable to pass null parameter in winform's event handler?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, entity-framework

i want to subsequently apply filters to my search Say " if I give 10K as the myFee value it should show all subjects with 10K Fees however if after this I give year 2014 it should show results applying both fee and year constraint simultaneously

currently, I am getting a correct result if I give values on both of my comboBoxes at the same time (Fee & Year)
[IMAGE IN BELOW]
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bo9Mr.jpg

Here we are calling GetStudentsByYearEF with parameters
but if i try to left any of the input null it will give error while passing as parameter.

```
            string _readYear = _yearInputBox?.SelectedItem.ToString();
            var _readFee = _feeInputBox?.SelectedItem.ToString();
            var readfee = Convert.ToInt32(_readFee);
            if (_readYear != string.Empty && readfee != null && readfee > 0)
            {
                var students = AcademyHelper.GetStudentsByYearEF(readfee, _readYear, this.dataGridView2, this, this.groupBox5);
                this.dataGridView2.DataSource = students;
            }
```

Definition of GetStudentsByYearEF()

```
    public static IEnumerable<Student> GetStudentsByYearEF(int fee, string year, DataGridView dtg, Form form, GroupBox groupbox)
    {
        List<Student> searchedStudent = new List<Student>();
        using (var retrive = new Models.Academy_MSDBEntities())
        {
            foreach (Control items in groupbox.Controls)
            {
                //removed .tolower() from here
                if (items.Name.AcademyContains("_courseInputBox") || items.Name.AcademyContains("_feeInputBox"))
                {
                    var query = retrive.Students
                     .Where(s => s.Year == year && s.Fees==fee).ToList();
                    searchedStudent.AddRange(query);
                    retrive.SaveChanges();
                }
            }
            return searchedStudent;
        }
    }
```

If want to subsequently apply filters on the search. however, it applies to search at once on pressing the search button but if I try to apply only Fee constraint on the search and leaving the Year constraint empty I gives me exception instantly.

Comment: What exception and where? Always include exact error information in the question

Comment: In the `Where` clause, you are always filtering year and fee. You should separate the filter in the where clause, if you only want to filter one of the criteria.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your where clause checks for both year and fee if `items.Name.AcademyContains("_courseInputBox") || items.Name.AcademyContains("_feeInputBox")`

So if your Academy contains the courseinputbox **OR** feeinputbox it will run the where clause. So if Academy contains courseinputbox but doesnt contain feeinputbox your where caluse will try and filter with the fee value.

You need to add a null check for fee before running your where clause. Something like:

```
if(fee != null){
                 var query = retrive.Students
                 .Where(s => s.Year == year && s.Fees==fee).ToList();
                searchedStudent.AddRange(query);
                retrive.SaveChanges();
}else{                                                              
               var query = retrive.Students
                 .Where(s => s.Year == year).ToList();
                searchedStudent.AddRange(query);
                retrive.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: Thank you, James, but the error is particularly coming at **var students = AcademyHelper.GetStudentsByYearEF(readfee, _readYear, this.dataGridView2, this, this.groupBox5); **  where i deliberately leave one comboBox empty to filter my search just according to Year (e.g 2014). i am not sure whether should i use OptionalAttribute or what ?? :( @James

Comment: Oh yeah that will teach me for trying to answer stackoverflow questions while at work. What is the exact exception you are getting? If fee is null surely when you try and convert it it will fail there with: Input string was not in a correct format.